# Normal to have 10,000 people walking back and forth on a single block, and zero right after

Tags: simcity-2013

See the picture(s) below.  Is this a bug in the game, or is this a problem I should correct?

[image]

Zoomed out for context

[image]

Comment: No worries, it's just a flash mob. :P

Comment: Do they reach their destinations?

Answer (score 1):

Pedestrian and cars are only a visual representation of the level of activity in regions of your city, they do not show if citizens are able to go to a destination or not. It can show if it is harder for them to go to a location since it is a good representation of traffic but it doesnt stop them.

What you see wont kill them or lower your city's profit. It CAN be considered a bug, since it is not normal pedestrian behavior and I dont think that the developpers wanted them to do that.

In any cases, don't worry about pedestrian traffic, only about cars, because having too much traffic can lower your citizen's happyness.

Answer (score 0):

At face value, it doesn't look like a  bug or problem to me. Sidewalks in simcity have unlimited capacity.

Unless there is a (different) problem you are concerned about, I don't think you need to worry.